# How to get the parts of a nodes content/text that are not part of a sub node

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nodes, nokogiri

I have XML that looks something like this:

```
<foo>my dog <bar>has</bar> <bar>fleas</bar> he gave <bar>to me</bar></foo>
```

When I want the `content` or `inner_text`  of the `<foo>` node  they return:

```
my dog has fleas he gave to me
```

How can I get this content in a way that `"has fleas"`, and `"to me"` are part of sub-nodes, and `"my dog "` and `" he gave "` are not wrapped in sub-tags,  preferably in order?

I assume there has to be so way of seeing the parts of the content/text and know this is root, this is sub, etc?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" along with the linked pages and "[mcve]". Your question isn't asked well. You gave us a little XML and then don't show us anything you tried: We need the minimum example of your code that shows the problem along with the desired output. I'm not voting to close, but please do those things in the future because they help us help you and help others searching for similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered both in Nokogiri's documentation, and in many answers about Nokogiri here on Stack Overflow.

The [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) documentation says:

> inner_text ⇒ Object Also known as: text
>
> Get the inner text of all contained Node objects

Whereas the documentation for [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method) says:

> content ⇒ Object (also: #text, #inner_text)
>
> Returns the content for this Node.

You can see this in action:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>my dog <bar>has</bar> <bar>fleas</bar> he gave <bar>to me</bar></foo>
EOT

doc.at('foo').text # => "my dog has fleas he gave to me"
doc.at('foo').children.map(&:text) # => ["my dog ", "has", " ", "fleas", " he gave ", "to me"]
```

Notice the blank string `" "`. That is the result of the space between

```
</bar> <bar>
```

While we humans like to think of that being nothing, in XML and HTML it's still a text node, so it shows up when walking through the `children`, since a text node is still a child. Normally a tighter selector would be used to avoid it, but in this case there's not a good way to do that because other strings being retrieved also have extraneous spaces. I'd probably do something like this instead:

```
doc.at('foo').children.map { |node| node.text.strip } 
# => ["my dog", "has", "", "fleas", "he gave", "to me"]
```

or:

```
doc.at('foo').children.map { |node| node.text.strip }.reject { |node| node.empty? } 
# => ["my dog", "has", "fleas", "he gave", "to me"]
```

Then using `join(' ')` results in:

```
doc.at('foo').children.map { |node| node.text.strip }.join(' ') 
# => "my dog has  fleas he gave to me"
```

or:

```
doc.at('foo').children.map { |node| node.text.strip }.reject { |node| node.empty? }.join(' ') 
# => "my dog has fleas he gave to me"
```

As far as knowing what's the `root`:

```
doc.root # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fecdc8a2434 name="foo" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a7984 "my dog ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fecdc8a795c name="bar" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a72a4 "has">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a7934 " ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fecdc8a790c name="bar" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a6e94 "fleas">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a78e4 " he gave ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fecdc8a78bc name="bar" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fecdc8a6a84 "to me">]>]>
doc.root.name # => "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Nokogiri to parse xml. It allows you to parse from a file or a string.

```
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML("<foo>my dog <bar>has</bar> <bar>fleas</bar> he gave <bar>to me</bar></foo>")

#to get text for <bar> elements
xml_doc.xpath("//bar").text()
=> "hasfleasto me"

#to get text for parent element <foo>
xml_doc.xpath('//foo/text()').text()
=> "my dog   he gave "
```

If you want any other format, work with arrays:

```
xml_doc.xpath("//bar").map(&:text).join(' ')
=> "has fleas to me"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the environment you are working in, but if you have access to XPath, this is simply `string(foo)`. The string() function returns the string value of a node, which is the concatenation of its descendant text nodes.